# ROS offline installation

Tags: ros, installation, download, offline

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Everyone,

I am trying to figure out a way to download ROS offline installer, so that I don't need to download it again and again for installing on different machines. So I am looking for such a way to download once and be able to install offline on different machines.

Does anyone know how would I do that? ( I cant find the offline installer downloadable anywhere on the web :| )

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!!

--
Regards,
-Neeraj

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9182/ros-offline-installation/) by [NeerajKulk](https://answers.ros.org/users/177/neerajkulk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-02-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know you posted this on [ros-users](https://code.ros.org/lurker/message/20110223.213801.6f1e1f5c.en.html), but I'll chime in again that when we do not want to download, like Nicola Fioraio mentioned, we install on one computer and then find and copy the archives from `/var/cache/apt/archives`.

This saves some time, since we can transfer over gigabit/flashdrive and then put the packages on a new computer. Then we just run the sudo apt-get install with all/most of the packages already present.

You might also want to look into [setting up your own local ros mirror](http://answers.ros.org/question/131/how-do-i-set-up-a-ros-mirror).  Downloading at 50 MB/s makes things nice. :D

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2011-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3